# Does MonoTouch support the wcf nettcp binding?

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, xamarin.ios, nettcpbinding

In Silverlight, it can load the assembly System.ServiceModel.Nettcp, but in MonoTouch I cannot find the assembly. Does MonoTouch support the WCF nettcp binding?

```
BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement messageEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement tcpTransport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
CustomBinding netTcpBinding = new CustomBinding(messageEncoding, tcpTransport);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoTouch does not ship with a `System.ServiceModel.Nettcp.dll` assembly.

That was not part of the Silverlight **core** assemblies for Silverlight 2-4 (i.e. that Moonlight implemented and shipped).

Note: Maybe it's one of the **extra** SDK assemblies that Microsoft allowed developer to redistribute (i.e. it was not installed with Silverlight itself but with SL-based application .xap). In such case you might want to try this assembly with MonoTouch to see if it works (since such case generally worked with Moonlight).